# What does WIN DEATH: android.osDeadObjectException mean?

Tags: android, react-native

I am testing my app on older Android versions. It runs fine on Android 4.4.4, but 4.3 seems to crash immediately upon opening the app. I have no idea what this error means:

```
W/dalvikvm( 9296): Invalid indirect reference 0xa4fdcc00 in decodeIndirectRef
I/dalvikvm( 9296): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xa4b86480 self=0xb79b6bd0
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   | sysTid=9296 nice=-4 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1217191904
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   | state=R schedstat=( 172387119 425972608 908 ) utm=10 stm=6 core=0
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.webkit.CookieManagerClassic.nativeAcceptCookie(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.webkit.CookieManagerClassic.acceptCookie(CookieManagerClassic.java:49)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.f.e.<init>((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.f.e.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.server.c.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.server.c.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.server.a.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.server.a.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.server.a$2.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.i.a.h.a((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.facebook.ads.internal.i.a.h.onPostExecute((null):-1)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm( 9296):
E/dalvikvm( 9296): VM aborting
F/libc    ( 9296): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 9296 (mycompany.myapp)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.3/JLS36G/eng.genymotion.20160825.132445:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): pid: 9296, tid: 9296, name: mycompany.myapp  >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #00  pc 00071022  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+194)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #01  pc 0007605d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z20dvmDecodeIndirectRefP6ThreadP8_jobject.part.36+77)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #02  pc 0007d8c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (GetStringUTFChars(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, unsigned char*)+97)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #03  pc 00535321  /system/lib/libwebcore.so (android::jstringToStdString(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*)+81)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #04  pc 00512d18  /system/lib/libwebcore.so (android::databaseDirectory(bool)+1048)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #05  pc ffffffff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b60  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b64  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b68  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b6c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b70  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b74  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b78  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b7c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b80  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b84  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b88  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b8c  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b90  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b94  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b98  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808b9c  46505845
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #00  bf808ba0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808ba4  b6137421  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808ba8  b6138894  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bac  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bb0  b7c8ad28  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bb4  b6137421  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bb8  b613790b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bbc  6c756e28
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bc0  0000296c
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bc4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bc8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bcc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bd0  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bd4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bd8  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808bdc  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #01  bf808dd0  b79b6bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808dd4  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808dd8  b6145838  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808ddc  a4fdcc00  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808de0  b79b6bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808de4  b603a016  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z20dvmDecodeIndirectRefP6ThreadP8_jobject.part.36+6)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808de8  b6185ccc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808dec  b60418c2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (GetStringUTFChars(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, unsigned char*)+98)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     #02  bf808df0  b79b6bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808df4  a4fdcc00  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808df8  00000012
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808dfc  b6059b79  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmChangeStatus(Thread*, ThreadStatus)+25)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e00  b75a06c0
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e04  99aa3734  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e08  00000016
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e0c  b6059b79  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmChangeStatus(Thread*, ThreadStatus)+25)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e10  b79b6bd0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e14  0000003c
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e18  bf808e00  [stack]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e1c  00000001
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e20  00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e24  9ddfb748  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e28  0000000c
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          bf808e2c  99e8a174  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):
I/DEBUG   ( 3470): memory map around fault addr deadd00d:
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     bf7ea000-bf80b000 rw- [stack]
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     (no map for address)
I/DEBUG   ( 3470):     (no map above)
I/BootReceiver(  332): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_06 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   Force finishing activity com.mycompany.myapp/.MainActivity
W/InputDispatcher(  332): channel '529a1e7c com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  332): channel '529a1e7c com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
D/        (  332): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7a01f78, tid 9372
D/Zygote  (  172): Process 9296 terminated by signal (11)
D/dalvikvm(  332): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2427K, 56% free 11576K/25772K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
W/InputDispatcher(  332): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '529a1e7c com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)'
I/WindowState(  332): WIN DEATH: Window{529a1e7c u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity}
W/ActivityManager(  332): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager(  332): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:635)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:990)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3834)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3766)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8344)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8221)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8900)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:8455)
W/ActivityManager(  332):   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
I/ActivityManager(  332): Process com.mycompany.myapp (pid 9296) has died.
```

I read a few things around here that mentioned the app might be doing too much, but it crashes on my login screen, which hardly does anything...

**UPDATE: After removing a bunch of dependencies one by one, I have narrowed down the culprit for my case to: https://github.com/callstack-io/react-native-fbads**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Dead Object Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037093/android-dead-object-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeadObjectException means you're trying to interact with an app that's already killed.  Frequently this happens when writing system services like keyboards.  It isn't your real problem though-  your real problem is the C stack trace above it.  You're attempting to access memory that has already been released on the Java side, causing you to segfault.  You can tell that by the 0xDEADDOOD address.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help lately. This started happening after I added the multidexing http://stackoverflow.com/a/42614521/1736601. App seems to build and run successfully on Android 4.4.4+, however is there a reason this might be occurring on Android 4.3 prior to KitKat?